# Error during initialization of boot layer javaFX on intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

The code for the module-info is :

```
module Schoolsys {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    //requires java.sql;

    opens sample;
}
```

My VM is `--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

the error is

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module Schoolsys not found
```

Schoolsys is my projectname.

I tried placing the file inside and outside the src folder, but still doesnt work. How do I fix this?

Comment: first follow a basic setup tutorial _to the letter_ (f.i. at https://openjfx.io/) - only after seeing the example compiling and running without errors, start work on your own project (f.i. by modifying the example) - no way around understanding in _detail_ what's going on. Note that random experiments like _placing the file inside and outside the src folder_ are a clear route into failure ..

Comment: @kleopatra I did follow the tutorial, but still getting the error.

Comment: are you saying that the example on that page is working as expected? If so, start modifying it in small steps, until it suits your needs :)